# CORS error in dev environment; works OK locally

Tags: c#, vue.js

I am trying to make an api call from a vue application to a .net core web api. Locally this works, when we then run it on our first dev environment we get this when it trys to make the request

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://bla-api/api/foc?page=1&pageSize=10&sortBy=&sortDirection=ASC'
>   from origin 'https://bla-api' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have added the following to the C#' Startup file in the **ConfigureServices** method. To just get it working I wanted to provide the *(wildcard), so let anyone call this. So presume that the named policy AllowAnyOrigin would do this!?

```
readonly string _SpecificOrigins = "AllowSpecificOrigins";

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(_SpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
})

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
```

then also added this in the **Configure** method

```
app.UseCors(_SpecificOrigins);
app.UseMvc();
```

What am I missing? I also try and make a fiddler request to the api and it breaks.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "What am I missing?" - basically make a request in chrome and look at the http output for the CORS options request? See what the server actually sends.

Comment: What does `_SpecificOrigins` refer to?

Comment: is your vue client http address added to _SpecificOrigins list?

Comment: If `_SpecificOrigins` has your frontend url. First thing check if specifying CORS in controller `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` fixes the issue. If so then it's probably this thing: "To enable CORS for your entire application add the CORS middleware to your request pipeline using the UseCors extension method. Note that the CORS middleware must precede any defined endpoints in your app that you want to support cross-origin requests (ex. before any call to UseMvc).". Or the error is in the frontend part add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in vue

Comment: Try including a single value for origin that matches your local url for the SPA. That should unblock you. You can always configure that setting in app settings

Comment: Updated with the _SpecificOrigins value, its just a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a red herring, the web api was not even deployed correctly, it was being deployued as a kestrel exe but was deployed as an azure web app. Adding a web.config pointing to the main api project resolved the issue. I did not write the deployment so that no needs looking at next. Presume the above question is fine then, cheers for the help